# How do I loosen nuts on bottom side of faucet are connected to each other

Tags: bathroom, plumbing-fixture

I am replacing a 4-inch spread faucet. The hot and cold water taps each have a big brass nut threaded under the sink (in addition to the basin nuts). These nuts are connected to each other by something I’ve never seen (I’ve only done about a half dozen sinks in houses I’ve had). I don’t know how to remove the piece connecting those nuts so that I can remove the nuts.  [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture from the top? Given the prominent "front" marking on that I suspect the whole thing pulls out the bottom, perhaps after undoing something above so that can happen.

Comment: Added a picture from the top.

Comment: We should close the question if the answer the op provided is deleted that doesn’t make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bottom-mount faucet.

I was able to pry out a plastic ring holding each side, and drop it down from the bottom.

See the hot water side in the picture.

A small screwdriver easily fit in the notch.

[image]

Comment: So the moral of the story is;  A small screwdriver was required to get your big brass nuts off ?