# Strange connection between hot/cold inlet shanks of faucet directly under the sink

Tags: bathroom, faucet

[image]I was expecting a 'normal' faucet but when I got under the sink to remove it, I found that there is some type of connecting 'tube' between the hot and cold side directly under the sink. There are no (obvious) screws/bolts holding it up and there is no flange that I can see to hold the faucet in place. The tubes are connected to rectangular 'nuts' that are attached to the threaded portion of the hot/cold inlet shanks.

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you use the edit button and look for mountain/snow icon to upload pictures.  It might be a temperature limit valve, so you don't burn yourself.

Comment: Having copper extensions from a faucet that end in ~3/8 NPT sounds like 100% normal to me I see this with both kitchen and bathroom faucets and have for years, makes them much easier to connect up, maybe a photo would help, but it sounds normal I have not seen separate temp valves, but I haven’t done much plumbing for quite a few years.

Comment: @crip659 That certainly sounds like what it could be.  Any idea how to remove it?  I can't get to the nuts with that thing in place.  (And, yes, that icon was up in the top menu...)

Comment: @Ed Beal Thanks for the comment.  I was just able to get a photo uploaded.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Found this question with the same set.  Looks like it is undone from the top, and dropped.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/200596/how-do-i-loosen-nuts-on-bottom-side-of-faucet-are-connected-to-each-other?rq=1

Comment: @crip659 Wow! That is exactly what I have!  I'll have to see how to disassemble it from the top.  Thanks again!